# psycopg2's sql.Identifier throwing "No function matching..." error

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

sql.SQL() works as it should, however I am having issues with both sql.Identifier and sql.Literal.  Both throw an error like this:

```
cur.execute(sql.SQL("""
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function identifier(unknown) does not exist
LINE 3:      Identifier('table_name')
             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

This is the code I am using:

```
cur.execute(sql.SQL("""
select 
  {}
from
  information_schema.tables
where
  table_schema = 'my_schema';
""".format(sql.Identifier('table_name'))))
```

I have followed the instructions as best as possible, and as far as I can tell, everything is correct.  I have imported sql from psycopg2 as well and established my connection.  If I remove the sql.SQL and sql.Identifier and just pass the sql as a string to execute, it works perfectly, however, I want it to be as safe as possible as other parts may have user input.  Am I doing something wrong, or is there a way to get this to work that I haven't stumbled upon yet?

Psycopg2 is fully up to date as well.

Comment: I've tried it as well with the same result, unfortunately.  I've updated the error to the full error, just in case, as that is with using single quotes now.

Comment: Just tried it, same result.  As far as I can tell, it's the Identifier function that isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

You're having errors because you're formating the query string and not the `sql.SQL` object.

Long story short:

```
from psycopg2 import sql

$> sql.SQL.format
>>> <function psycopg2.sql.SQL.format(self, *args, **kwargs)>
```

So, if you format directly your string you'll end up with a wrong SQL query (not well formatted):

```
$> query = sql.SQL("""
    select {} from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'my_schema';
    """.format(sql.Identifier('table_name')))                              
$> query.as_string(conn)                                                 
>>> "select Identifier('table_name') from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'my_schema'; "
```

Otherwise, if you format the `sql.SQL` object:

```
$> query = sql.SQL("""
   select {} from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'my_schema';
   """).format(sql.Identifier('table_name'))
$> query.as_string(conn)
>>> 'select "table_name" from information_schema.tables where table_schema = \'my_schema\';'
```

[More informations about: sql.SQL.format(*args, **kwargs)](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.SQL.format)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer when taking a deep dive into the sql.py file within psycopg2.  It seems the instructions don't list it, but it requires `.as_string(conn)` to precede the identifier/literals.  Once added, everything worked as it should.